# Unable to run Windows Container with Docker - Virtual hard disk limitations

Tags: windows, security, docker

I'm trying to run Windows in a container for vulnerability research for an assignment and keep getting this error:

[Error Message Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkV2F.png)

I've taken the compression off of `\ProgramData\Docker` and `\ProgramData\DockerDesktop` and still get the error.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this? Linux containers are working fine for me it's just any Windows container that gives this error.

EDIT:
Compression is also turned off for the location where it's trying to go (I changed the default path to try and fix it)

[image: Image of compression being disabled]

Comment: Just to confirm: compression is off the D:\ProgramData\Docker\windowsfilter ? The error message shows that it seems your docker are going to your D drive (and you didn't specify in your question)

Comment: Yeah sorry, forgot to put that but yes, compression is turned off for that